# Ubuntu fails to boot after upgrade from 18.04 to 19.1

Tags: boot, upgrade, 19.10

Yesterday I upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 installation to 19.10 (configuration is a dual-boot with Windows 10). The upgrade concluded successfully and I used the computer for several hours without any issues, then shut it down.

On boot-up this morning, Ubuntu hangs at the purple start-up screen (without reaching the GRUB screen), and a stream of error messages appears on the second monitor.

The error messages all start with either

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): could not resolve symbol .... AE_NOT_FOUND....
```

or

```
ACPI Error: Aborting method....due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND)....
```

or

```
drm:si_dpm_set_power_state [radeon] *ERROR* si_set_sw_state failed
```

I've tried to interrupt the boot sequence by holding down <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> keys without success.

I've also tried booting from an Ubuntu 18.04 bootable CD without success (I hear the drive reading the CD, but Ubuntu fails to boot from the CD).

So, I'm stuck. I'd really appreciate any suggestions for how to resolve this. I'd be happy to revert back to 18.04 LTS if I could, but so far do not have a way to do this given that I can't boot from the CD drive (perhaps due to incorrect boot sequence).

Comment: There is no supported upgrade path from 18.04 LTS to 19.10 because upgrades are step-wise and the version in between, 19.04 has passed end of life. If you wait until August 2020, there will be an upgrade path to the next LTS release 20.04 LTS. -- If your computer could run Ubuntu18.04 when installed, it is also possible to run it live from a DVD disk or USB pendrive, maybe with some tweaks. What computer is it (brand name and model) and what graphics chip/card is there (brand name and model)?

Comment: The computer is a home-build: Gigabyte GA-Z77kX-UD3H motherboard, Intel i5-3570K processor, and MSI AMD Radeon graphics card (sorry about lack of additional details, but all I can do is read the info off of the installed components). I'd be happy to revert back to 18.04 LTS if I could, but so far do not have a way to do this given that I can't boot from the CD drive (perhaps due to incorrect boot sequence).

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in the first place? Have you checked with `md5sum` in another computer that the downloaded iso file is correct and that the DVD disk works? There could be an error during burning. Have you tried the modern way, to boot from a USB pendrive? Finally, have you tried with the boot option `nomodeset`?

Comment: If I am remembering correctly, I installed 18.04 from the same DVD that I tried to use today. For additional info on this issue, see "answer" I provided below.

Comment: If you installed 18.04 from the same DVD that does not work today, the DVD drive may be failing (or the DVD disk is scratched). Or you forgot that you had to use a [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808). You could also [make a USB boot drive and try that way ...](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer to my original question, but I'm including it in case it is useful to someone. After a number additional reboots and other troubleshooting steps, Ubuntu 19.10 completed its boot sequence successfully. That behavior has continued following numerous additional reboots. I have no idea of what changed the boot behavior, but whatever the problem was it prevented me from entering the BIOS setup (using the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key) and precluded booting from the DVD drive. Now that the unknown error has disappeared, both options work again. Not very satisfying, but at least Ubuntu is operational again.